# SQL Update not erasing data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to update a column where type is text and there is previous text with some text. And Ihave to add some text in front of all the text what was before.
Could this look like this:

```
Update table1 
   set info = concat ( 'my text ' , info)
where id=3
```

But why text should be in the first row.

Comment: What do you mean with "should be in the first row"? What's wrong with your statement? What is the error you get?

Comment: Your SQL looks fine to me.  What is this doing that you do not want?

Comment: i have never done that before so i asked would that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is the syntax of `concat` function in PostgreSQL.

```
concat(string_val_1, [string_val_2, string_val_3, string_val_4,... so on])
```

You can pass one or more than arguments as per your need in PostgreSQL.

Result will be string_val_1 [appended by string_val_2 appended by string_val_3 appended by string_val_4 ...]:

```
string_val_1[string_val_2string_val_3string_val_4 ...]
```

**Example:**

```
concat('stack', 'over') --> gives you- stackover
concat('stack', 'over', 'flow') --> gives you- stackoverflow
concat('stack ', 'over ', 'flow') --> gives you- stack over flow
```

Comment: i would like that gives me --> 
stack
over
flow

Comment: It's just an example. There is a space followed by `stack` and `over` as you can see in input parameters. So you have spaces in output also. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Request you select my answer as correct answer if it has resolved your problem.

Comment: i have text contect

for example:
<br>text1</br>
<br>text2</br>
<br>text3</br>

and now i have to make it look
<br>stackoverflow</br>
<br>tex1</br>
<br>tex2</br>

Comment: If text1, text2 and text3 are columns of some table then you can do like `concat('stackoverflow ', text1, ' ', text2, ' ', text3)`. If they are also string literals you can do like- `concat('stackoverflow ', 'text1 ', 'text2 ', 'text3')`.